# Why did Bobbi go into this trouble?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the latest episode, S02E15 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*,

> Bobby went into trouble of stealing Fury's cube herself prior to the attack by "real" S.H.I.E.L.D. When the "real" S.H.I.E.L.D. was going to attack and gas everyone in the Coulson's S.H.I.E.L.D. base, why did Bobbi steal Fury's cube prior to attack?

Why couldn't she do that after the attack which would be much easier?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the original plan was to gas everyone, however once Hunter escaped she asked to be reinserted to steal the Toolbox. I think they gave her a set amount of time before they were going to execute the original plan regardless of her success.

Answer (score 4):

After Agent Hunter escaped from "Real SHIELD", they have no idea about what he would do or where he would go next. It was safe to assume that after finding out that Bobbi and Mac were double-agents that he would want to warn his friends and colleagues in Coulson's team, and as such "Real SHIELD" realised that they might not have much time before their cover was blown. This spurred them into action.

Even in the event of "Real SHIELD" successfully taking Coulson's SHIELD by surprise, there is a very real chance that there are various protocols in place to protect, or even destroy, Furys toolbox. For all "Real SHIELD" know, as soon as an internal alarm is tripped, the box is automatically fired into the sun. Even if that isn't the case, it is likely that one of the expert agents on Coulson's team (such as Agent May) would make a beeline for Fury's toolbox once they realised what is going on.

As such, it was decided that they would use Bobbi's cover as a member of Coulson's team to attempt to secure Fury's toolbox before they attacked, which provided "Real SHIELD" with the greatest possible chance of successfully completing their mission before their cover was blown.

Comment: Hunter did escape, yes, but it's irrelevant here because he couldn't couldn't contact anyone for next 12 hours.

Comment: When it comes to alarm thing, it's also out of option because they were going to gas them.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Even if they were gassed instantly with a 100% success rate, the Toolbox could have still been automatically destroyed if it detects toxic fumes, or a break in, or a multitude of different things that could alert a system to the fact that something wasn't right.

Comment: If that's the thing, couldn't Fury's cube self-destruct when Bobbi tried to laser cut its container?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Potentially. But they already had the cube at the point, which is one step further than they were before they attempted to get it.